# Spurious regression - are the coefficients biased or not?

Tags: time-series, spurious-correlation

Say that we are regressing a variable $Y_t$ on another variable $X_t$, and both series are non-stationary. Specifically, let's say that both are $I(1)$ and trend upwards over time.

Now, say we regress: $$Y_t = \alpha + \beta X_t + u_t \tag{1}$$

I have always been under the impression that the coefficient $\hat{\beta}$ from this regression is biased, due to the problem of spurious regression. I've also been told that another way of thinking about it is that there is an omitted variable $t$ in (1) which causes the coefficients to be biased.

Today, someone told me that actually the coefficients are unbiased, and it is simply the standard errors from estimating (1) which are wrong.

What is the truth?

EDIT: Assume that $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are NOT cointegrated.

Comment: Is $X_t$ a variable for time?

Comment: @Dayne Apologies - edited the typo.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using OLS method  for estimation and and $X_t$ is exogenous variable, there are three cases with regards to the estimated residuals $\hat{u}_t:

1. $\{\hat{u}_t\}$ are uncorrelated. If so, the estimate $\hat{\beta}$ is not only unbiased but also efficient.
2. $\{\hat{u}_t\}$ is stationary but not uncorrelated. If so, the estimate $\hat{\beta}$ is unbiased but the standard errors can be *improved* by using ECM.

The above two cases are that if cointegration (or that that both series have linear time trend).

3. $\{\hat{u}_t\}$ is non-stationary. In this case also $\hat{\beta}$ is unbiased but standard errors reported are practically meaningless. This is the case of spurious regression. This, I think, means that the model is incorrect so there's no sense of estimating such a model (this last statement needs confirmation!).

Comment: why are you making statistical assumption on the residuals? Should it not rather be on the errors $u_t$?

Comment: Absolutely. Theoretically it will be $u_t$. It's just that I was writing from the practical perspective. As in you get $\hat{u}_t$ only from data.

Comment: Please note that residuals $\hat u$ from an OLS regression are related to the errors $u$ via $\hat u=Mu$, where the "residual-maker matrix" is $M=I-X(X'X)^{-1}X'$. So $Var(\hat u)=MVar(u)M'$, which reduces to, assuming classical assumptions on the *errors*, $MM'$, which equals $M$ due to symmetry and idempotency of $M$. Now, $M$ is *not* a diagonal matrix even if $Var(u)$ is.

Comment: @ChristophHanck: This mean that in any regression (not restricting to time series), we should not expect residuals to be uncorrelated, even if the true errors are? How do we check for independence of true errors then?

Comment: It rather means that such tests will typically be based on asymptotic approximations. Consider the simple case of $X=\iota$, a vector of ones, i.e., a regression of a constant. In that case, you can easily check that the off-diagonal elements of $M$ equal $-1/n$, which evidently tends to zero as sample size $n$ grows.

Comment: And this will be true in general also, is it? As in the off-diagonal elements will tend towards zero as n approaches infinity?

Comment: If $Y_t$ and $X_t$ are I(1) and NOT cointegrated, then it does not matter what the properties of the error terms are.  It's spurious regression in each case because the OLS assumptions are not met.  You'll be regressing a trending variable versus a trending variable which is not legal in OLS because $u_t$ can't be stationary unless $Y_t$ and $X_t$ are cointegrated. ( engle and granger, 1987, econometrica ).

Comment: Revisiting this after a while due to recent comment by @mlofton. My answer is clearly wrong as I am making comments about residuals. In any case, I think a ts trending upwards should not be called I(1) as the latter is generally used for unit root process which is a stochastic trend. The term cointegrated should also be used to series which have a common *stochastic* trend.

Comment: hi dayne: I think that's true that I(1) usually refers to stochastic trend. In fact, there's a whole literature on deciding whether a series has a stochastic trend ( so that it's difference stationary ) or has a trend that's deterministic ( trend stationary ). See Nelson and Plosser, 1982 I think for a discussion of that.  But, in either case, using  OLS on two variables that are not I(0) AND not cointegrated will be spurious because the OLS assumptions are not met.